# REGEX Expression C#. Split string by whitespace outside the quotation marks

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I'm trying to define a regular expression for the Split function in order to obtain all substring split by a whitespace omitting those whitespaces that are into single quotation marks.

Example:

key1:value1 key2:'value2 value3'

i Need these separated values:

- key1:value1
- key2:'value2 value3'

I'm tried to perform this in different ways:

- Regex.Split(q, @"(\s)^('*\s*')").ToList();
- Regex.Split(q, @"(\s)(^'.*\s.*')").ToList();
- Regex.Split(q, @"(?=.*\s)").ToList();

What i am wrong with this code?

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `k1 : v1 k2 : 'v2 v3'` a valid input? And if so what output do you expect?

Comment: Are you trying to parse JSON? Do not use a regex for this. Use JSON.NET.

Comment: @AleksAndreev , no this not a valid input
Only this: ---> k1:v1 k2:'v2 v3'

only with one space between each parameter
In this case, i expect to see:
  - k1:v1
  - k2:'v2 v3'

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, this is not a JSON
is a part of a URL (AWS Cloudsearch parameters)

Comment: Is there a working answer below? If yes, please consider accepting.

Comment: The "regular" in "Regular Expressions" has a very specific formal definition. What you're asking to do may be possible in a modern engine, but it falls outside that definition for regular text, and therefore won't be simple. You'll likely to do much better with a purpose-built state machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var st = "key1:value1 key2:'value2 value3'";
     var result = Regex.Matches(st, @"\w+:\w+|\w+:\'[^']+\'");

    foreach (var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
```

The result should be:

```
key1:value1
key2:'value2 value3'
```

Comment: I'm checking this, and looks like very close... 
actually key1 and key2 could be any word (is a fieldName). The same for value1, value2, and value3
Should I Use \w* is this case, instead of key and value?
something like:

   -             var result = Regex.Matches(st, @"\w*:\w*|\w*:\'\w*.*\'");

i tried to use it but something not working, but i know that is very close

Comment: @Sebastian \w+ i would use. I will update the answer

Answer (score 2):

A working example:

`(\w+):(?:(\w+)|'([^']+)')`

```
(\w+)       # key: 1 or more word chars (captured)
:           # literal
(?:         # non-captured grouped alternatives
(\w+)       # value: 1 or more word chars (captured)
|           # or
'([^']+)'   # 1 or more not "'" enclosed by "'" (captured)
)           # end of group
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wev10i/1)

Your try:

> (\s)^('\s')

`^` means beginning of line, `\s` is a white-space characters. If you want to use the not-operator, this only works in a character class `[^\s]` -> 1 character not a white-space.

Comment: In this case, should i use Regex.Matches instead of Regex.Split?

Comment: In Java, you would do `while (Matcher.find()) { String key = Matcher.group(1), etc`. I don't know about c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "key1:value1 key2:'value2 value3'";
            string pattern = @"\s*(?'key'[^:]+):((?'value'[^'][^\s]+)|'(?'value'[^']+))";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key : '{0}', Value : '{1}'", match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I'm checking this, and looks like very close... 
actually key1 and key2 could be any word (is a fieldName). The same for value1, value2, and value3
Should I Use \w is this case, instead of key and value?
something like:

   - string pattern = @"\s*(?'\w*'[^:]+):((?'\w*'[^'][^\s]+)|'(?'\w*'[^']+))";


Also, the with the solution that you propose i miss the last single quota

Comment: The names 'key' and 'value' are just group names in regex.  I like using the names instead of the group index numbers.